# checking for upper limit on joint

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, jointjs

Trying to check for joint limits with the following:

```
    sliderJoint = transform.GetComponent("SliderJoint2D") as SliderJoint2D;
    if (sliderJoint.limitState === "UpperLimit") {
  }
```

But I'm getting the error 
"== cannot be applied to jointLimitState and string"

how can I know when the joint has reached it;s limit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to compare an object to string. [JointLimitState](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/JointLimitState2D.html) or in this case limitState has LowerLimit & UpperLimit. I am assuming you should be doing something like

`if (sliderJoint.limitState.UpperLimit > someValue)`